# How to fix the memory leaks in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I built a simple app which gets the reports from HockeyApp. However when I run the app with the memory leak instruments, it showed there was a memory leak when I perform the getReport action. I couldn't understand all the information shown in the instrument.

Here is the button action method which causes the memory leak:

```
- (IBAction)getReports:(id)sender {

//initialize url that is going to be fetched.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/APP_ID/crash_reasons"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:tokenReceived forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-HockeyAppToken"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.getReportConnection = connection;

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{

    if (connection==getReportConnection) {

     [self.receivedData appendData:data];

     NSLog(@"data is %@",data);

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *e = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
    NSLog(@"login json is %@",JSON);
     NSLog(@"reason json is %@",JSON[@"reason"]);

    [JSON[@"crash_reasons"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


        [reportArray addObject:obj[@"reason"]];
         NSLog(@"index = %lu, Object For title Key = %@", (unsigned long)idx, obj[@"reason"]);
    }];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Array: %@,array count is %d", jsonArray,jsonArray.count);
    }

   // [reportArray addObject:[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    if (JSON!=NULL) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Reports succesfully retrieved" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }

       }
}

 // This method receives the error report in case of connection is not made to server.
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

UIAlertView *errorAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Wrong Login" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[errorAlert show];
NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
}

// This method is used to process the data after connection has made successfully.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

}
```

I see that the memory leak occurs just before the alert view appears in the `didRecieveData` method.

Here is the screenshot of the memory leak instrument showing memory leak:

[image]

I couldn't understand which part of the code causes the memory leak. Can anyone tell me how to identify the part of code that causes the memory leak with the leak instrument?

**Edit:** When I run the app on the simulator, the instrument didnt show any memory leak:

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Again When I run the app on device, the instrument showed me the memory leak:
[image]

I looked into the leaks section and I found `NSmutableArray` is causing the leak:
[image]
[image]

I used only one `NSMutableArray` in my code. I declared it in `.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *reportArray;
```

and allocated it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
reportArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and loaded it in `didRecieveData`:

```
 [reportArray addObject:obj[@"reason"]];
```

Stacktrace snapshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that one of the Instruments buttons, just above "Snapshots" on the right, selects a stack trace that can show how the allocation of the leaked object happens.

Comment: Added the stack trace snapshots!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
reportArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` and `connection:didFailWithError:` methods set

```
reportArray = nil
```

and finally in **Project > Build Phases > Compile Sources** add `-fno-objc-arc` as compiler flag **for this file** *(edited, sorry)*. Then click Product menu >Analyze *(command + shift + B)* again and check if the memory leak still occurs.

Comment: P.S. also allocate and initialize `reportArray` in the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` method.

Comment: I am using ARC. I think I can't mention autorelease.

Comment: I see that. If you add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to a specific file in the **Build Phases > Compile Sources** file list, ARC will be disabled for this file.

Comment: I didnt see any leaks after analyzing . The leaks were shown only on the instruments

Comment: Still, does the 'autorelease' idea works for you? It works fine for me in all my apps.

Comment: I will try it. I fear if I disable ARC, I need to take care of everything,and some where I might end up with more of these leaks.

Comment: With this flag added in the Build Phases, you disable ARC for this specific file only, not for all files.

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the paths of my files :) Company policy.... So, here is my XCode with the project I am working on right now: http://i.imgur.com/q9A6VkM.jpg

Comment: I analyzed it and there is a leak at this line :  NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82318/discussion-between-lucifer-and-t-77).

Comment: Why do you allocate NSString from the NSData argument and then NSData from this NSString. Why don't you use the parameter directly (i.e. `    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];`
This way `NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and `NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it is Apple's leak -- sure looks like it is coming from UIAlertView / UIAlertConnection.  You might try implementing the alert using UIAlertConnection and see if it goes away -- Apple may not have tested the back-compatible UIAlertView implementation as much.

It won't show up in leaks, but be aware that NSURLConnection retains its delegate, and in your case you have your delegate retaining the NSURLConnection it looks like.  That should be a retain loop if I'm not mistaken.  Be sure to break it (nil out the delegate, or nil out the connection on your controller) when the connection finishes or fails.